# Can I use Singleton pattern to decouple my viewModel from the Android framework and objects like Context?

Tags: android, singleton, viewmodel, android-viewmodel, solid-principles

I have an API class that I need to pass `Context` to set some parameters, and I initialize it in my activity's `onCreate()` like this:

```
val apiClient = ApiClient.getInstance() // gets a singleton instance
apiClient.setParameters(this) // passing context here

val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[MainViewModel::class.java]

setContent {
    MyAppTheme {
        Navigationhost(
            navController = rememberNavController,
            mainViewModel = viewModel
        )
    }
}
```

Then in my `mainViewModel` class I do operations using the `ApiClient` by getting an instance of it again:

```
val client = ApiClient.getInstance()
val client.getMessages()
```

Is this the right way to decouple my `viewModel` from the Android framework and things like `Context`? If the singleton `ApiClient` instance has the `Context` object, does it mean my `viewModel` also has it if it gets the `ApiClient` instance?

I know I can use DI/Hilt, but should I? I don't want to complicate the app unless I really have to. Appreciate any thoughts/pointers.